# The number of ways to distribute groups between professors. Combinatorics. Surjective problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I supposed that I could use Stirling numbers to solve the following problem. So S(m, k) where m = 7 and k = 5 would be 140. But it appears to be wrong.

There are 5 professors of biology and 7 different groups of students who are going to take a biology course. Each professor may teach any group. Find the number of ways to distribute the groups between professors provided that every professor must take at least one group.

Please, help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

${7\brace 5}$ (or $S(7,5)$, if you prefer) is the number of ways to partition the $7$ groups of students into $5$ parts. It would be the answer if the professors were indistinguishable, but they aren’t. Thus, any one of those partitions can be distributed to the professors in $5!$ different ways, yielding a final figure of ... ?